# Does the agent noun always come from the perfect participle stem?

Tags: derivation, participle

When answering [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/8944/79), I wrote that an agent noun is always derived from the perfect participle stem.
As the (singular masculine form of the) perfect participle is listed in many dictionaries, deriving agent nouns is easy:
*amatus > amator*, *cursus > cursor*…
This simple principle works well and means that one does not need to memorize the agents and the participles separately.

But are there any exceptions?
Are there individual verbs or groups of verbs that do not follow this pattern?
I am only speaking about agent nouns ending in *-or* derived from the verb, so pairs like *ductus–dux* are excluded.

Comment: Maybe related to [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/8913/1459)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently not always, but exceptions seem to be rather marginal and hard to find.

"The morphome [sic] vs. similarity-based syncretism", by Donca Steriade, says that *-⁠sor* agent nouns invariably correspond to *-⁠sus* perfect participles, but gives examples in (23) of *-tor* agent nouns that don't correspond to *-tus* participles: *converritor* vs. *versus* from *verrī* 'to sweep', *Imporcitor* (the proper name of a god) vs. *imporcātus* from *imporcāre, infenditor* 'advocate' vs. *-fensus* from *-fendere, libritor* 'hurler' vs. *librātus* from *librāre, favitor* (alongside *fautor*) vs. *fautus* from *favēre,* and *deversitor* vs. *deversātus* from *deversārī* ([p. 131, *The Morphome Debate,*](https://books.google.com/books?id=rlOsDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA131) edited by Ana R. Luís and Ricardo Bermúdez-Otero, 2016).

Furthermore, page 141, Steriade lists *[lūdor](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=ludor)* 'player' as an example of a word where the suffix takes the form *-or* rather than *-tor* or *-sor;* the regular variant *lūsor* also exists.

However, Kodner 2022 writes

> Several of Steriade’s examples (Steriade 2016: ex. (22)–(23)) turn out to be post-Classical or even Medieval (e.g., *fīcitor* cf. *fīca* Nonius Marcellus fl. late 3rd c., *Imporcitor* contra *imporcātus* Servius Honoratus fl. late 4th c., *bibitor* (no PPtc) Apollinarius Sidonius ob. 488, and *infenditor* contra *-fensus* in a 16th c. glossary attributed to a ‘Vulcanius’), meaning that the attested writers were at best native speakers of Late Latin. Since Late Latin lost contrastive vowel length, we cannot be sure whether they are faithfully relaying the Classical language.

(footnote 27, "What learning Latin verbal morphology tells us about morphological theory", *Nat Lang Linguist Theory* 41, 733–792 (2023). https://doi.org/10.1007/s11049-022-09553-2)

"The Suffix -tor-: Agent-Noun Formation in Latin and the Other Italic Languages", by Margaret M. T. Watmough (1995/1996), says that the PIE rule for forming *-tor* nouns was accented full grade of the verbal root + *-tor,* but describes forming these nouns on the perfect participle stem as an "Italic rule" that developed later on. Many words apparently have a form that is compatible with either rule (p. 84).